Understanding the Difference Between Accessing Columns and Using Methods with Parameters in Pandas
I'm working with pandas in Python and often find myself confused about when to access columns directly and then use methods, versus using methods that take parameters. For example, I see code that uses dot notation to access a column and then applies a method, like this:
total_sales = df.column.sum()

But then there are other methods that directly take parameters, like this:
exploded_df = df.explode('column')

Are there any general rules or guidelines to help remember which approach to use?
Thank you!
Sometimes I mix them up, writing code that's wrong, like this:
exploded_df = df.column.explode()


The first is for operating on a specific column, the second operates on the entire dataframe.

In addition, using an attribute to access a column is not a good practice. Better use df['column'].sum()

In general: 1) Read the documentation for each method to understand the data it returns 2) Choose the method that returns the minimal data that you require

Basically, Example 1 is summing up the values of the specific column, the rest of the data frame has no relation to the function.
df.column is a individual series which has nothing to do with the original dataframe.
OTOH, df.explode('column') returns the entire data frame, it also changes the values of the other columns as well, not just the specific column.
The reason why df.column.explode() doesn't work is because explode is a function for data frames, not series and specific columns.
To sum it up, if you don't want to mix them up, think of your desired output and required data. If you want a data frame as an input, then use df.<method>. If you want a column to be the input, then use df.column.<method>.
Btw, to be more clear, remember that df.column is not a function, it's just another (less recommended) way of writing df['column'].

Thank you! It's helpful to think about the desired output and the input. And thank you for pointing out that df.column is a less recommended way of writing df['column']. I learned the dot and bracket notation from codeacademy but they never explained when each one should be used. I'll just stick to bracket notation from now on.
